# Files Column on Acumatica Grid not displaying the highlighted icon upon refresh

Tags: file, grid, icons, customization, acumatica

I am new to acumatica and I have a grid on customization project and I have enabled the files column via setting the file Indicator flag to true.

I see my file is getting uploaded.
However, when I refresh my screen, I see the file icon back to original state.

( I have added NoteID in my DAC which adds the notes and attaches the file, the only issue is the with the file icon)
Would appreciate thoughts on this.

Comment: Please add your sources of the DAC and PXGraph to the question

Comment: If you have custom code inserting the file attachment it's possible there's a DAC record Update and/or Persist call missing. In that case icon would show because the change was done in memory but reloading the page would remove it because it was never persisted to DB